# OnClick event not working. Is there something wrong with my event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have this piece of code, I want to show replies after the click event but it doesn't seem to fire or render.

```
      // function for rendering comment's replies
    const renderReplies = (comment) =>{
        if(comment.data.replies){
            return (
                <div className="reply">
                    {comment.data.replies.data.children.map(reply => {
                        if(reply.data.body){
                        return (
                            <div className="comment-card">
                                <span className="comment-author">{reply.data.author}</span>
                                <ReactMarkdown>{reply.data.body}</ReactMarkdown>
                                <div className="upvotes">
                                    <ImArrowUp id="comment-arrow-icon" /> 
                                    {reply.data.score}
                                </div>
                                {showMoreReplies(reply)}
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                    })}
                </div>
            )}}


    const showMoreReplies = (reply) => {
        if(reply.data.replies){
            return (
                <span className="show-all-replies" onClick={() => renderReplies(reply)} >Show more replies <HiArrowNarrowRight className="show-more-replies-arrow" /> </span>
                
            )
        }
    }
```

If I execute `renderReplies()` within itself like this:

```
</div>
   {renderReplies(reply)}
</div>
```

then the replies show up properly. The only issue is that I want them to show up after click event. I could use  `display: none` but since I have a lot of comments with their own replies it will be a bit complicated

Comment: Do you see output if you use `onClick={() => console.log('hello')}`?

Comment: yes, console log is working on click

Comment: Then the event is fine. Something is wrong with the `renderReplies` function

Comment: I checked the function, as I said if I use renderReplies without event listener it shows everything as it should. I'm kinda stuck on it tbh

Comment: Consider doing some debugging? Does `comment.data.replies` exist when `renderReplies(reply)` is run?

Comment: yes, replies have the same structure as comments so i can pass reply as an argument and everything should be working. believe me i tried debugging but i just cant seem to find what the issue is. I guess I will just change the way it is shown

Comment: Re your just-deleted question: The problem is you're clicking the `div` or `p` element inside the `li`. It's only the `li` that has the `id`, but `target` is the innermost element that was clicked -- if you clicked the `div` or `p`, `event.target.id` will be blank, it's only not blank if you click somewhere on the `li` that isn't covered by those child elements. You want [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead, which is the element the event listener is attached to (both in the DOM and in React).